# Should I _really_ remove dylibs after installing homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I just installed homebrew and saw a message from the install script that said I should consider removing the following "evil" dylibs as they might break builds. Has anyone done this? And if so, did you later find out that you actually needed them?

Here's the dylib list:

```
/usr/local/lib/CHBrowserView.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgnsdk_musicid_file.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgnsdk_sdkmanager.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libjson.0.0.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libmusicid_osx.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.0.0.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.0.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.0.0.0.dylib
```

Comment: i am not sure if you should, however, the [github page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) for homebrew is very active and may be a good forum to try as well. UPDATE - [this gentlemen thinks you will be fine.](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6871)

Comment: The word "evil" was a poor choice by brew.  I've mentioned this before (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/8546)  Not sure if they're still using the same terminology these days.

Answer (score 21):

NO. If you have something in /usr/local/lib, in all likelihood its because you built it and installed it.

It's an annoying and egotistical error message for Brew to assume that any libraries in /usr/local/lib are 'evil' simply because Brew doesn't know about them.

It is possible that you might have an 'older' version that conflicts with something Brew builds, but.. guh. It'll be painfully obvious when the program dies. And more likely than not if the application tries to dyload it, it also means that when Brew is building things it'll try to *link against the old lib anyway*. As long as  it's arch / version compatible it's no biggie.

It'll also be painfully obvious when something you built pre-Brew can't find the shared library you removed. And given that you may not have the source laying around (or remember how you configured it in the first place..)

I strongly suggest keeping the old libraries around.

Comment: I followed the suggestion and deleted the files. Then discovered that nokogiri had been built against one of them, so I had to ditch my whole gemset and reinstall. Luckily rvm and bundler makes this fairly easy. It certainly seems foolhardy to just go ahead and do it, though the pretty install script did make it seem like the right thing to do :)

Comment: As a general warning to people - I would strongly suggest avoiding brew. The mechanisms and practices it employs aren't the cleanest. It's still the fastest route to get arbitrary packages installed but most recipes are so old that it's hardly worth it. If anything use their recipes as a guide for what setting you may need to make or patches to apply - but review them carefully. I've seen some really sad 'port' recipes.. No offense brew guys, I get what you're trying to do.. It's just not my style.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel Do you have any recommendation or alternative to homebrew instead?

Comment: @jose.angel.jimenez The only real solution is 'build it yourself'. The fact that brew doesn't even compile packages makes me uncomfortable. It seems to just download packages compiled by 'somebody on the internet', which, if you're paranoid about security is a giant neon warning.  These days you just need to get the GNU stuff (automake, autoconf, etc etc) and after that the majority of packages ./configure && make. Not the best solution but it's the most unixbeardy.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel I wonder how downloading a binary differs from downloading a source and then running it? Unless, of course you choose to either write the source or read it through.