# Brew Doctor Warning

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I see the following when I run `brew doctor`:

```
    Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFFileMonitor.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFsqlite3.7.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFSyncEngine.I.dylib
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this warning and potentially fix the problem?

Comment: see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539170/should-i-really-remove-dylibs-after-installing-homebrew

Answer (score 3):

This particular set of files appears to be from Citrix Receiver; I received the exact same message after installing brew, and a bit of googling turned up http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1188699

I'd recommend leaving them in place unless you no longer need Citrix.